# Unable to inject SessionRegistry with Spring boot 3.1.1 and Spring Session Redis

Tags: spring-boot, spring-session

I would like to use the `removeSessionInformation` method on `SessionRegistry`

I've read that with Spring Boot, the `SessionRegistry` bean should already be configured and ready to use. However, I don't seem to be able to inject/use it and get the error:

```
required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistry' that could not be found
```

(this happens when I simply try to inject a `SessionRegistry` with constructor injection. (nothing unusual) )

I'm using `spring-session-data-redis` along with `spring-boot-starter-security`, `spring-boot-starter-data-redis` and of course, `web`. It's a blank project with these dependencies and a controller that's trying to inject `SessionRegistry`.

I'm aware that I can probably just provide my own bean config for that .. something like this:

```
@Bean
public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
    return new SessionRegistryImpl();
}
```

(from this SO answer: [Could not autowire SessionRegistry in spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51666583/could-not-autowire-sessionregistry-in-spring-boot))
but this is no use to me as it's not giving me the `SessionRegistry` that was automatically configured by boot that uses redis, but a new, emtpy one - which is totally not useful from what I can see?

My question(s):

1. How can I get Spring Boot's configured `SessionRegistry` when using spring session with redis + is there even one to use?
2. Do I need to configure it manually + if so how do I do it so it works with all the automatically configured redis stuff?